# Table with dynamic content (rows) taking too much height

Tags: css, angular

I have a regular table with table rows that are generated with ngFor loop.. the issue is the following: Even though I have set css of table-wrapper to `max-height: 450px` and `overflow-y: auto;` , it doesnt matter, that div gets the scroll needed, but my entire page, entire body element, has the height of that table with every single row... Anyone had similar issue?

```css
.table-wrapper {
  display: block;
  max-height: 450px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-wrapper">
  <!-- I'm reproducing the DOM after Angular ng for  -->
  <table>
    <tr *ngFor="let s of something">
      <td>Some content</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Not normal and definately has nothing to do with Angular, it's a CSS issue. Show us the full CSS regarding .table-wrapper and the table in it? Does the div have display:block and the table display: table, tr has table-row etc? How about css position of all the elements?

Comment: can't reproduce on my own, if you would include the markup after the loop runs, would be helpful.

Comment: @funkizer table-wrapper has display: block and table is just a regular table. I mean, this is the first time I have this issue, nothing extraordinary in the css, just height and overflows

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa there is nothing unusual, its just a table inside a div, with max height and overflow, thats why its weird... not the first table im working with :D

Comment: Clearly it's neither the table nor the css, probably something in that collection is messing things up.

Comment: Most likely @ZohirSalakCeNa

Comment: Could be caused by your windows height? Maybe you need to work with "vh" css unit

Comment: Tried all of that as well, nothing that works @bruce182

Comment: Wasn't the issue replication correct on my editing?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "my entire page, entire body element, has the height of that table with every single row"? Can we see the result as an image or, even better, can you reproduce it in a stackblitz?

Comment: @ConnorsFan The scroll on body element is scrolling all the way down, but the body height is not equal to the scroll :)

Comment: Please, post an image of the issue. It's not clear yet.